# How many maximum number of subqueries can you put in a single hive query?

Tags: sql, hive

I am working in MySql. Hive, to be particular.

Comment: Please improve your question

Comment: Share more details please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such limit, however, you can refer the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Subqueries+in+SELECT) for kind of subqueries are supported.